Make custom Link in java keycloak plugin for reset user password to send it to user from my own email service
I want to make reset password link for user when i register user using admin api without any temporary password and want to send it using my own email service.
How can i make the link? as i have keycloak session object and adminevent object which i am using to capture user register event and i can successfully able to get userId and based on that i can get userModel.
Thanks in advance.
String token =
    new ExecuteActionsActionToken(userModel.getId(), userModel.getEmail(), 10,
        actions, null, clientModel.getClientId())
        .serialize(session, realmModel, session.getContext().getUri());

I tried this code to generate the UPDATE_PASSWORD Action token and was able to send in the user email, but when I open the link with this token, it is an action expired message
